# Memory leak in assignment operator

Tags: c++, memory-leaks, operator-keyword

In my program I have to overload the = operator. The overloading function looks like:

```
Polygon &Polygon::operator=(const Polygon &source)
{
    this->capacity = source.capacity;
    this->index = source.index;
    this->vertex = new Vertex[source.capacity];

    for(int i = 0; i < source.capacity; i++)
    {
        this->vertex[i] = source.vertex[i];
    }

    return *this;
}
```

But if there is one thing I have learned is that I am responsible of deleting things i create with the "new" keyword.

So before returning I tried with:

```
delete vertex;
```

But that didn't work since it deletes the object which I just copied to.
So I tried with:

```
delete source.vertex;
```

Which crashed my program during runtime.

I have tried alot of other ways also, but they are just tries with thought behind.
I would really like your help, not only giving me what I should write, but how I should think in these scenarios.

Comment: Use `delete[]`, not `delete`. `new` pairs with `delete`, and `new[]` pairs with `delete[]`.

Comment: `delete[] this->vertex;` before `this->vertex = new Vertex[source.capacity];`. Also, make sure you "delete" it in destructor.

Comment: <unpopular opinion puffin> Since I'm using C++11 capable compilers, I see `delete` as a code smell… </unpopular opinion puffin>

Comment: Why not save yourself a lot of fiddly memory management by using `std::vector`, rather than reinventing it?

Comment: It's a course I read through school. I'm hoping the teacher has a reason we aren't allowed to use it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Before this statement

```
this->vertex = new Vertex[source.capacity];
```

insert statement

```
delete [] this->vertex;
```

Also the operator must look the following way

```
Polygon &Polygon::operator=(const Polygon &source)
{
    if ( this != &source )
    {
       this->capacity = source.capacity;
       //...
    }

    return *this;
}
```

Comment: I do have the if(this != &source), I just didn't add it because I thought it would be too much info that does not regard the matter. But thanks.
I also did what you said, and I think what threw me off was that I had to delete BEFORE using new, not after.

Comment: It would be interesting to hear why my answer was downvoted.:)

Comment: @VladfromMoscow Yup, I'm curious too. Some `shared_ptr<>` religious fanatic?

Comment: @ Petr Budnik In this case the question should be downvoted not my answer.:)

Comment: @VladfromMoscow Well, you got my upvote right away. And I find it seriously wrong to downvote anything without some sort of an explanation if none was given earlier in the comments. And this answer is clearly a correct one, so it's simply unfair. Let's hope the person who downvoted made a mistake and will correct it.

Answer (score 2):

The program probably crashed because you used `delete` to delete a pointer created with `operator new[]` (not `operator new`). These are two different things. You always have to match the two, using `delete[]` with `new[]`:

```
int *p = new int;
delete p;

int *q = new int[10];
delete [] q;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't delete vertex there because the object is still referencing it.  The destructor for `Polygon` should be responsible for deleting the `Vertex` objects it creates:

```
~Polygon::Polygon()
{
    if (vertex)
        delete[] vertex;
}
```